# How can I add an image in the page header when printing Excel 2000 spreadsheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, microsoft-excel-2000

I'm using Excel 2000. I have a spreadsheet document that covers several pages when printed. I am able to add page numbers and basic text to the header (and footer) of the printed sheets, but I would really like to add an image to the header in addition to the basic text. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Excel [does not provide this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268071) for custom headers or footers in Excel 2000. A workaround is also given on that page.

Here is a workaround given on [ExcelTip.com](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Adding_a_Picture_to_a_Header/Footer/202.html).

To add a picture (such as a company logo) to the header/ footer in Excel 97 and Excel 2000:

1. Select cell A1.
2. From the Insert menu, select Picture, and then select From File.
3. Select the picture you want, and click Insert.
4. Adjust the picture to the height and width of the row.
5. From the File menu, select Page Setup.
6. Select the Sheet tab.
7. Select Rows to repeat at top.
8. Select row 1, and then click OK.

Comment: That does the trick. Thank you `:)`

Comment: Nice to help. You're welcome.