# How to limit a pivot table to show only centain number of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table of rooms which must be cleand by employees. The table has two columns: "Person" and "Room Location". This list updates every month, but with the same column title.

I have to print this list every month on a pre-designed form, and with the following criteria:

- Each page must contain only the rooms for one "Person".
- Each page has only 10 rows. Therefore, if there are more than 10 rooms for a person I have to divide it into more pages.
- Some of employees are not included every month. But, the employees list is alwasy fix.

My Questions:

1. Is there any way to limit the pivot table up to 10 rows and tell to excel to continue the rest into another pivot?
2. Does anyone have any other suggestion to do the same thing with UDF.

The main list:
[image: The main list]

The form to print:
[image: The Form to Print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your 1st question, no it's not possible to split the result over several PivotTable.

Each page contain only one employee > you can automatically add a page break for each person so:

1. Right-click the Person label in the PivotTable, and then click Field Settings.
2. In the Field Settings dialog box, on the Layout & Print tab, add a check mark to Insert Page Break After Each Item.

Since you want to begin on each page at the same place, I would print the column headers on each page:

1. Right-click on the PivotTable and open the Options dialog box
2. On the Print tab, add a check mark to Set print titles

If you want to print only 10 rows per page, then I would change the margins under page layout in order to reduce the height available per page. So you force to have a page break all 10 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The page break of pivot table has a big limit for me: I want to keep the header and footer in all pages. My header and footer are too complex to insert them by means of page layout command in excel. Therefore, I have to add them by myself. I cannot even insert them as image, because they contain some VLOOKUP variables. I can fix the top side in the page layout options, but I cannot fix the buttom.

Comment: If your header are static, then you could eventually [insert them as picture](http://superuser.com/questions/190224/how-can-i-add-an-image-in-the-page-header-when-printing-excel-2000-spreadsheets)